When optimizing a portfolio for risk parity, can any portfolio weights turn negative?
As the title reads, when performing risk parity optimization (equal risk contribution amongst all assets to the portfolio volatility), is it possible for weights to turn negative?
I understand that in the regular portfolio optimization, it is necessary to set a short sales restriction, if not it is possible to have negative weights in the mean-variance optimization or the "burst" of weights.
However, I saw that in packages of R such as "riskParityPortfolio" there isn't a selection for short sale restrictions. Does that mean that the risk parity optimization inherently does not result in negative weights?

This seems like the right answer.

I suppose my point is it's not that risk parity OUGHT to produce a non negative solution. I thought that was the question.

Many risk-parity implementations simply use the
inverse-vol rule (i.e. weights are proportional to 1
over vol), and then all weights are (strictly) positive
by construction.
A number of implementations that do the full optimization
indeed set non-negativity as an
explicit constraint.  But in general and without such
constraints, negative weights may occur when you
equalize risk-contributions (though negative weights
may be unlikely).
An example in R for a 4-by-4 covariance matrix, which is of rank 4 and positive definite:
S <- structure(c(0.000366309632978563, -0.000105943107569848,
                 -0.000119667135542588, 0.000169622848883779,
                 -0.000105943107569848, 0.000187730511335559,
                 -6.49497066288097e-05, -0.000167162505503921,
                 -0.000119667135542588, -6.49497066288097e-05,
                 0.000102201079006482, 1.88829418811814e-05,
                 0.000169622848883779, -0.000167162505503921,
                 1.88829418811814e-05, 0.000208993337170307),
               dim = c(4L, 4L))

The implied correlation matrix:
cov2cor(S)
##        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
## [1,]  1.000 -0.404 -0.618  0.613
## [2,] -0.404  1.000 -0.469 -0.844
## [3,] -0.618 -0.469  1.000  0.129
## [4,]  0.613 -0.844  0.129  1.000

I do not use the riskParityPortfolio package, but it
seems to support negative weights, though the default is to not allow them:
library("riskParityPortfolio")
riskParityPortfolio(S)
## $w
## [1] 0.2313 0.2990 0.4588 0.0109
## 
## $relative_risk_contribution
## [1] -1.9471 -0.0858  1.5197  1.5132
## ....


riskParityPortfolio(S, w_lb = -1)
## $risk_concentration
## [1] 1.93e-14
## 
## $w
## [1] -0.0829  0.4391  0.2167  0.4271
## 
## $relative_risk_contribution
## [1] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
## ....


Additional note: The example covariance-matrix hides some fairly-strong dependencies between the asset returns, which may not be obvious from looking at the data:
library("NMOF")
R <- randomReturns(na = 4, ns = 100,
                   sd = sqrt(diag(S)),
                   rho = cov2cor(S), exact = TRUE)
pairs(R)


Computations based on such a matrix (such as a marginal-risk calculation) will typically be sensitive and react strongly to small changes ("perturbations") of inputs. In the example, you can get around this by increasing the iterations:
w <- riskParityPortfolio(S)$w
FRAPO::mrc(w, S)
## [1] -194.71   -8.58  151.97  151.32

w <- riskParityPortfolio(S, maxiter = 1e4)$w
FRAPO::mrc(w, S)
## [1] -67.3  11.2  78.2  77.9

w <- riskParityPortfolio(S, maxiter = 1e5)$w
FRAPO::mrc(w, S)
## [1] 23.1 24.7 26.1 26.1

w <- riskParityPortfolio(S, maxiter = 1e6)$w
FRAPO::mrc(w, S)
## [1] 25 25 25 25

(I use the marginal-risk function mrc from Bernhard Pfaff's FRAPO package.)
But of course, this is all the result of an empirical problem (not a computational one): the assets are highly-correlated, and so an algorithm will always have trouble differentiating between linear combinations of those assets.

Very interesting example, thank you.

Oh wow, this is actually very worrying. It seems like what the package is saying is that IF we do not allow negative weights, the optimization will result in unequal relative risk contribution for the sake of maintaining the positive weights.

There might be such cases, but here it is rather a result of the chosen matrix. I have added to my answer.

Thank you @EnricoSchumann for your detailed answer. This will most probably go into my code, but its definitely interesting to see the tradeoff between the number of iterations and the convergence to the true solution (weights/mrc)
